# Phonegap Issue connecting to localhost php webservice with jsonp

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am writing simple phonegap+framework7 app which needs to fetch data from localhost url.

What ever I do it does not work for me

```
var app = new Framework7({
    // App root element
    root: '#app',
    name: 'My App',
    id: 'com.domain',
    panel: {
      swipe: 'left',
    },
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/about/',
        url: 'about.html',
      },
    ]
  });
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {  
    var REMOTE_SERVER_URL = http://localhost/projects/ajax/get.php;
    app.request.json(REMOTE_SERVER_URL + "?callback=?", function (res){console.log(res)})
});
```

in the end getting following error

> Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost/projects/ajax/get.php?callback=f7jsonp_1548277709852”

the php script header

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

I have tried both localhost and my local IP, both gives the same error, if I copy the link into browser it works fine

Here is meta for policy

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 
'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 
'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * 
data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 
'unsafe-inline'">
```

Not sure why

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'">

Comment: `http://localhost/projects/ajax/get.php;` Is this a typo, or should this not be a string?

Comment: its a string in config file, I just copy to here without quotes sorry